# Google Play Permissions compliance

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-permissions, google-play-console, ussd

We have Xamarin Android App for an Airline, the core use of the app is for Booking and Purchasing ticket, recently we have added new functionality which allows customers to pay with USSD Option, and purchase their ticket. While uploading the app to play store. it is asking us to select the Core functionality of the app.

among the lists which core functionality do I have to select?

we have added the below permissions on manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have  SMS-based fincancial transactions, that's the option you should select.

It's not a matter of what you choose that will get your app selected or rejected either way.

Comment: as per your recommendation, selecting this option resulted in rejection of the app